# How does Apache know which site to load when having multiple sites at the same port?

Tags: port, subdomain, apache-2.4

I have setup 2 sites at my localhost. One at localhost:8197 and one at fc.localhost:8197
Of course, to make this work, I've edited my /etc/hosts file to include

```
fc.localhost    127.0.0.1
```

So, these are my configurations for each site respectively:

000-default.conf (site located at localhost):

```
<VirtualHost *:8197>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

fc.conf (site located at fc.localhost):

```
<VirtualHost *:8197>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/alex/Documents/fc/Website/fc/html
    ServerName fc.localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /home/alex/Documents/fc/Website/fc/html>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Suppose that my local IP address is 10.8.210.51 and some pc in my local network puts 10.8.210.51:8197 in
the address bar of their browser, then apache on my side will serve the first site (localhost) and not the
second one (fc.localhost). The same things happens if I put 127.0.0.1:8197 in my address bar (server-side).

So, my question is, out of clear interest, how does Apache decides which site to serve and how can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your specific case: apache will serve the FIRST overlapping virtual host. Since 000-default is before fc.localhost in the alphabet the first virtualhost is loaded and served.

To answer what i assume is the follow up question:
You can host many sites on the same IP:PORT using [namedVirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)

This technology relies on the [Host Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#Host) in the HTTP spec.

And because of complications with SSL https virtualhosts are possible via [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

Answer (score 1):

This is called "name based virtual hosting", described [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html):